# IRouteHandler gives Resource could not be found error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following IRouteHandler class in asp.net MVC project used to upload a file via ajax:

```
public class UploadHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();
        return httpHandler;
    }

    public class HttpHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        #region IHttpHandler Members
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpFileCollection SelectedFiles = context.Request.Files;
                for (int i = 0; i < SelectedFiles.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile PostedFile = SelectedFiles[i];
                    string FileName = context.Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/" + PostedFile.FileName);
                    PostedFile.SaveAs(FileName);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write("Please Select Files");
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Files Uploaded Successfully!!");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And javascript:

```
var uploadfiles = $("#upFile").get(0);
        var uploadedfiles = uploadfiles.files;
        var fromdata = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < uploadedfiles.length; i++) {
            fromdata.append(uploadedfiles[i].name, uploadedfiles[i]);
        }
        var choice = {};
        choice.url = "Upload";
        choice.type = "POST";
        choice.data = fromdata;
        choice.contentType = false;
        choice.processData = false;
        choice.success = function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < uploadedfiles.length; i++) {
                model.Filename(uploadedfiles[i].name);
            }
            $("#lblWait").hide();
        };
        choice.error = function (err) { alert(err.statusText); };
        $.ajax(choice);
```

And in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.Add(new Route("Upload", new UploadHandler()));
```

But the ajax just gives a Resource could not be found so I assume something is wrong with my routing somehow, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Got this working in the end by using a controller action instead like:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void UploadFile()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection SelectedFiles = context.Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < SelectedFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile PostedFile = SelectedFiles[i];
                string FileName = context.Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/" + PostedFile.FileName);
                PostedFile.SaveAs(FileName);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Please Select Files");
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Files Uploaded Successfully!!");
    }
```